# Oracle Forms Call Certain Canvases of Multiple Forms from Custom Menu (mmb)

Tags: oracle, menu, menuitem, oracleforms

I have one main form (`"users.fmb"`), one other form (`"cards.fmb"`) and one custom menu (`"menu.mmb"`).  I want to call `canvases` of forms according to which menu item selected.

For example: When I choose 1. item of menu, call canvas A of "users" form. When I choose 2. item of menu, call canvas B of "cards" form. Menu("menu.mmb") is related with main ("users") form.

How can I do this?

I tried to use

```
CALL_FORM, OPEN_FORM, GO_BLOCK, SHOW_VIEW, SET_WINDOW_PROPERTY
```

methods in different ways but it not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your menu is only attached to **users.fmb**, you won't be able to call again **users.fmb** from **cards.fmb** (except by exiting **cards.fmb**).

Also if you call again **users.fmb** from **cards.fmb** you will have 3 forms in your calling stack (users.fmb -> cards.fmb -> users.fmb), which is not a good idea.

I guess you would have to create another form acting as the main screen from which you can run either **users.fmb** or **card.fmb** (you can use `CALL_FORM` for this).

Also you can use `SHOW_VIEW` to display a specific Canvas but you will have to do this in the targeted Form.
You can pass the canvas name as a Form parameter (called e.g. "navigation_canvas") and in the `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger, if this parameter is not null you can then navigate to the desired canvas using `SHOW_VIEW(:parameter.navigation_canvas)`